# Calling the Angular router in TypeScript

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a button in a page like this:

```
<button [routerLink]="['../edit', 14]">Test</button>
```

So, if I'm at `http://localhost/dashboard` and click the button, I'm redirected to `http://localhost/dashboard/edit/14`, which is exactly what I expected.

Now I need to do the same in Typescript. I injected the `Router` service in my class and tried the following:

```
this.router.navigate([`../edit/${item.id}`]);

this.router.navigate([`/edit/${item.id}`]);

this.router.navigate([`edit/${item.id}`]);
```

But none is working, all of them redirect me to my starting page with no errors.

Does the `Router` need some extra setup?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to specify that you are routing relative to the current route. Here is how this can be done:

```js
@Component({...})
class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  go() {
    this.router.navigate([`../edit/${item.id}`], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
}
```

Here are [Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html#!#relativeTo-anchor) describing the relativeTo property of the `NavigationExtras` class

Comment: import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router'; // This is how you import Route and ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add the children routes on your app.module.ts:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
    [{
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'edit/:id',
                component: EditComponent,
            }]
    }])
```

Comment: Yes, it's done. I didn't include in the answer because I don't think it's a problem with the routes setup, because I can navigate to it using the `routerLink` in HTML